# My own library wont include

Tags: ros, library, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have made my own library, and i want to include it in an other package, but i keep running in to this problem:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "lib_polygon" with
  any of the following names:

    lib_polygonConfig.cmake
    lib_polygon-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "lib_polygon" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "lib_polygon_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "lib_polygon" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ci-rss-golfpicker/ci-ros-common/ci_executors/path_recorder/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'lib_polygon'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "lib_polygon" with
  any of the following names:

    lib_polygonConfig.cmake
    lib_polygon-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "lib_polygon" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "lib_polygon_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "lib_polygon" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  ci-rss-golfpicker/ci-ros-common/ci_executors/path_recorder/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/bonde/catkin_ws/golfpicker/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/bonde/catkin_ws/golfpicker/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

My library cmake file:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(lib_polygon)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  ci_msgs
  msgs
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
# )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ci_can_lib
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp ci_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(ci_can_lib
   src/simple_Polygon.cpp
 )


## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(ci_can_lib
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/ci_can_lib.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
add_dependencies(lib_polygon
${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
ci_msgs_gencpp
msgs_gencpp
)

## Declare a C++ executable
# add_executable(ci_can_lib_node src/ci_can_lib_node.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(ci_can_lib_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(ci_can_lib_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
 install(TARGETS lib_polygon
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
 )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_ci_can_lib.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

and my package cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(path_recorder)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  std_msgs
  roscpp
  message_generation
  nodegen
  nav_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  lib_polygon
  msgs
)

## node generation
generate_nodemodel(model/path_recorder.rnd)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
  FILES
  Polygon64.msg
)

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
add_service_files(
  FILES
  RecordPolygon.srv
  EndPolygon.srv
)

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
    DEPENDENCIES
    std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  nav_msgs
)

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
##INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES path_recorder
   CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime std_msgs nav_msgs geometry_msgs lib_polygon
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)


###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
  ${NODEGEN_INC}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(path_recorder ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
add_executable(path_recorder_node
    src/path_recorder_node.cpp
  src/Recorder.cpp
  #src/simple_Polygon.cpp
    ${NODEGEN_SRC}
)

## Add dependencies to the executable
add_dependencies(path_recorder_node
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_genmodel
  lib_simple_polygon
  msgs_gencpp
  ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_msgs
  ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencpp
)

 ## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(ci_bq27000_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(path_recorder_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

# path_recorder path_recorder_node
## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
 install(TARGETS path_recorder_node
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
 )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_path_recorder.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

Hope you can help me figure out what i am doing wrong

Edit: I pasted the wrong cmake file for the library, it has been updated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248621/my-own-library-wont-include/) by [neobonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/27909/neobonde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
> ```

```
  [..]
  lib_polygon
  [..]
)
```

Your "library package" is called `ci_can_lib`, but your `path_recorder` package searches for `lib_polygon`?

If there is no `lib_polygon`, then Catkin (really: CMake) will emit those errors.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0